# Velero installation failing from a VM host in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-iam

I am trying to install `velero` on a `GKE Cluster` from a `GCP Compute Engine Host`  using below steps

https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero-plugin-for-gcp

I am installing `velero` from the `VM` host  using below command

```
 velero install --provider gcp --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0 --bucket ${VELEROBUCKET} --secret-file ./credentials-velero
```

but it is failing with below error

```
Error installing Velero. Use `kubectl logs deploy/velero -n velero` to check the deploy logs:
Error creating resource ClusterRoleBinding/velero: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: 
User "116865650821658545991" cannot create resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope: requires one of ["container.clusterRoleBindings.create"] permission(s)
```

To resolve this error , I am trying with this

```
  kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-binding --clusterrole cluster-admin --user velero
```

but this too failing with below error

```
error: failed to create clusterrolebinding: clusterrolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "116865650821658545991" cannot create resource "clusterrolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" at the cluster scope: requires one of ["container.clusterRoleBindings.create"] permission(s).
```

Two queries for the above scenario

1. Is it correct to create `clusterrolebinding` resource to resolve the error I am seeing while installing `velero` ?
2. How to identify the corresponding user for "116865650821658545991" as seen in second error and what role needs to be assigned to create `clusterrolebinding` resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is resolved now.

I identified the service account used by `VM` using

```
   $ gcloud config list
   [core]
   account = 235897301806-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

After that we assigned the role "Kubernetes Engine Admin" to the above `Service account` and installed `velero` using below command successfully

```
VELERO_BUCKET=gkevelerobackup
velero install --provider gcp --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.1.0 --bucket ${VELEROBUCKET} --secret-file ./credentials-velero
```